# Find arc length from irregular 2d points

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, computational-geometry, arc-length

[image]

As Displayed in Image above,we are having irregular closed curve.

To do processing I need to divide curve into equal parts and find all separate segments. For that I want to know how exactly we can divide curve in equal parts. I tried searching solution for that and found that I first need to get "arc length", I am having points for this graphical presentation but I have no idea about equation how I can find arc length curve.

At now I have Input Given is : List of 2d points for finding arc length.

P.S : I need to implement this whole calculation c#

Comment: You may need the arc's function...and what in the world is "2d points" ?

Comment: Your question should be how to find perimeter of a polygon with given the vertices. Now do you list of 2d points are ordered or are they arbitrary. BY order I mean, do you get the polygon by joining points (A[1], A[2]), (A[2], A[3]), ...(A[n-1], A[n]), (A[n], A[1]) in which case you can just take the length of pairs and sum them.

Comment: If you want to set up equally spaced points on an regular curve, you need a parametric representation such that the parameter is proportional to the arc length, in other words, if the parameter is time, then a point moves along a curve at a constant speed. Even for simple curves such as ellipse, finding this parametrization is hard. For irregular curves the same condition can apply, with parametrization now described by piecewise functions... This makes problem harder